# Why localhost works even apache is off?

Tags: apache

I installed ZendServer CE.
This is my /usr/local/zend/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file: http://codepad.org/vorWrTKb

This is my /etc/hosts file.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%losd0   localhost
```

Document root is **/Users/anthony/apache/html**

If I turn zend server off http:/localhost/ still works.
Moreover I have another web-site (php) here /Users/anthony/apache/html/somesite and it also still works on localhost.

At the same time I haven't any virtual hosts in /usr/local/zend/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf having that documentRoot.

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file http://codepad.org/qx20aZua

I checked default apache macos service and removed file from /etc/apache2 httpd.conf.

**If ZendServer is on:**

127.0.0.1 runs /Users/anthony/apache/html/ (correct)

localhost runs /Users/anthony/apache/html/somesite (it shouldn't)

**If ZendServer is off:**

127.0.0.1 runs /Users/anthony/apache/html/somesite (it shouldn't)

localhost runs /Users/anthony/apache/html/somesite (it shouldn't)

So I cannot understand how localhost works if apache doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved.

I run *ps aux | grep httpd* and got a lot of process.
I've killed each process and restarted ZS. Now it's ok)